Shared data access in pthreads
My questions are : How many values ​​can the output of the following code take? What are these values? What is the reason for different values? How can we prevent different values ​​from occurring?
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int shared_data = 100;


void* thread_function(void *args)
{
    long temp;
    long *j = (long *) args;
    temp = shared_data;
    temp = temp + &j;
    shared_data = temp;
    
    return (NULL);
}



int main() 
{

long i = 0;
long tinfo[] = {1,2,3};
pthread_t ids[3];

for(int i=0 ;i<3;i++)
{
    pthread_create(ids+i,NULL,&thread_function, &tinfo[i]);
}

for(int i=0 ;i<3;i++)
{
    pthread_join(ids[i],NULL);
}

printf("shared data = %d\n",shared_data);

}


I was working on system programming and operating system and saw this exercise. I have tried to make a research but the topic is very new to me. It is not an homework or exam question, It is one of the past interview question of an institution.

The threads are all modifying common data with no controls to prevent concurrent access.  The behaviour is completely undefined and there are no useful predictions that can be made.

long *j = (long *) args; -- aside: you don't need to cast void pointers in C.

"How can we prevent different values ​​from occurring?" - In order to get a defined behavior, synchronize the threads.

The calculation temp = temp + &j; is dubious — you're adding the address of a local pointer variable to the computation.  You should probably be using temp += *j; to add the value that the pointer points at.  Your compiler should be shrieking about the addition — and you should be paying attention to your compiler's shrieks!  The variable long i = 0; is unused.

You probably need to use a pthread_mutex_t (mutex — mutual exclusion) to control access to shared_data (see pthread_mutex_init() and so on).  At least, that's the simplest way to deal with the problems of concurrent access.  It won't speed things up, but it will make them more reliable.  There's still no sequencing — what happens depends on the idiosyncratic behaviour of the thread scheduling on your particular machine — but there would be less undefined behaviour.

First thing first, make the code compile with -Wall -Werror.

The title to your question should ideally be a summary of the question or reference the subject of the question.  "Shared data access in pthreads" for example might be a better title.  This is not really an example of "system programming" - it is an issue encountered multithreading in general.

Assuming an answer is expected rather then a correction to the many flaws which are likely unintentional, in answering this question, you would do well to state some assumptions to deal with the "undefined" behaviour of the poorly formed code.  Doing so would demonstrate your knowledge of such issues should the question in fact be intended to be about that, but it also allows you to answer the question in the manner the institution probably intended. They ,may even fix the question for next candidate!  Unfortunately the world is full of such flawed interview questions - if you want to gain entry to the course, you need to play the game.  But you may not want to enrol if this is indicative of the quality of their teaching perhaps.
Anyhow, if we state:
Assumptions:

The code runs on a single core one active thread at a time.
Each thread once started will run to completion without being pre-empted by any of the other threads without synchronisation or mutual exclusion.
All access to shared_data will be explicit despite the lack of volatile qualifier.

Then the output variability will depend on the order in which each thread starts - which need not be the order in which they were created.  As such it is a question of permutations of 1,2,3 which is 3 x 2 x 1 = 6.  So the answer then is a matter of performing the thread function calculation for each to the six possible permutation of execution order.
Without the assumptions the result is entirely undefined.
Given those assumptions the "fix" is not to use threads at all, but to call the function sequentially in a single fixed order.  No doubt there are more complicated solutions using thread synchronisation, but there is no practical benefit of run to completion threads in a defined sequential order.
